# Prediction intervals for generalized least squares model with heteroscedastic errors

Tags: confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, prediction-interval, generalized-least-squares

I wanted to model some data with heteroscedastic errors using a `gls` model of the form

```
library(nlme)
gls(y ~ x, data = data, weights=varPower(1, form= ~y))
```

That is, with the variance being a power function of the dependent variable `y` (or the independent variable `x`?). See link [here](http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/11.html#9) for an example.

For my application I would also need 95% prediction intervals on the model predictions for a specific value of `x`. Would anybody know how to calculate these for a `gls` model with this kind of error structure? (`gls` does not appear to provide for a `predict` method with `interval="prediction"`) Or alternative approaches that would allow for such an error structure and allow me to calculate prediction intervals? (A solution using weighted regression is posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186953/calculating-prediction-intervals-from-heteroscedastic-data/186956#186956), but I would prefer to use `gls` instead, as that fits the appropriate power coefficient describing the mean-variance relationship)

Comment: Is it possible to apply robust, sandwich based standard errors to the GLS model? I think it is, but I don't know if it's been implemented.

Comment: I had been looking around to see if this could be done, but I couldn't find how to do that so far...

Comment: I gave an answer. I think it can be done. The issue, I didn't see in the subtext of the title, is that sandwich doesn't give prediction intervals. It is about inference on regression coefficients. To obtain prediction intervals, you have to explicitly model the heteroscedasticity, above and beyond specifying a covariance structure. Consider using splines for the residuals: I have an answer about doing this here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37943/simultaneous-heteroscedasticity-and-heavy-tails-in-a-regression-model/320097#320097

Comment: OK I deleted the "answer" since it was not the answer to the question you were asking, but I reposted it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331840/how-to-calculate-sandwich-standard-errors-for-generalized-least-squares-models/331841#331841) if the method is still of any interest. It should be a useful example of manipulating these kinds of data, and using the splines approach I recommended.

Comment: how about quantile regression?

Comment: Hmm I used quantile regression before but often had fitting problems with the quantreg package unfortunately, so I'd like to stick with gls if possible...